# Can't get constant from dynamic class using namespaces

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, constants

I'm not able to get a constant from a class which is defined by using a string variable and PHP 5.3. namespaces. Example:

```
use \Some\Foo\Bar;

$class = 'Bar';
echo $class::LOCATION;
```

where LOCATION is a properly defined constant. The error I get says class Bar is undefined.

If I instead do

```
$class = "\Some\Foo\Bar";
```

everything works fine.

Is there anyway to make the first example work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `$class::CONST` to get a class constant, it is required that `$class` contains a fully qualified classname independent to the current namespace.

The `use` statement does not help here, even if you were in the namespace `\Some\Foo`, the following would not work:

```
namespace \Some\Foo;

$class = 'Bar';
echo $class::LOCATION;
```

As you have already written in your question, you have found a "solution" by providing that fully qualified classname:

```
use \Some\Foo\Bar;

$class = "\Some\Foo\Bar";
echo $class::LOCATION;
```

However, you dislike this. I don't know your specific problem with it, but generally it looks fine. If you want to resolve the full qualified classname of `Bar` within your current namespace, you can just instantiate an object of it and access the constant:

```
use \Some\Foo\Bar;

$class = new Bar;
echo $class::LOCATION;
```

At this stage you do not even need to care in which namespace you are.

If you however for some reason need to have a class named `Bar` in the global namespace, you can use `class_alias` to get it to work. Use it in replace of the `use \Some\Foo\Bar` to get your desired behaviour:

```
class_alias('\Some\Foo\Bar', 'Bar');

$class = 'Bar';
echo $class::LOCATION;
```

But anyway, I might not get your question, because the solution you already have looks fine to me. Maybe you can write what your specific problem is.

Comment: Take, it works for *all* of the following code, there will always be a class named `Bar` in the global namespace from the `class_alias` call ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to a class name using variables as in `$class::MYCONSTANT` or `$class::myStaticMethod()`, PHP assumes that you have given a fully qualified name, i.e., an absolute path to the class. In your case it was `\Bar::LOCATION`. (The initial backslash is optional here, actually it is deprecated.) Aliases defined by the `use` keyword are ignored. Thus you get the error that `\Bar` class is not defined.

The `::class` notation (introduced in PHP 5.5) will resolve aliases to the fully qualified names, so `Bar::class` will be resolved to `Some\Foo\Bar` including the namespace:

```php
use Some\Foo\Bar;

$class = "Some\Foo\Bar";
// is the same as
$class = Bar::class;

echo $class::LOCATION;
```

The `::class` notation works not only with class names. The phrase `static::class` stands for the "Late Static Binding" class name given by `get_called_class()`. Furthermore, if class name does not exist at compile time, it is silently resolved to the current namespace: `NonExistent::class` is the same as `__NAMESPACE__ . '\NonExistent'` (or simply `'NonExistent'` when not in a namespace). The latter can also be **misused** to define constants within the current namespace:

```php
namespace Foo;
define (ANGLE_10_PERCENT::class, 180*asin(0.1)/M_PI);
// is the same as
define ('Foo\ANGLE_10_PERCENT', 180*asin(0.1)/M_PI);
// which is approximately 
const ANGLE_10_PERCENT= 11.5;
```