# Expanding PHP namespace alias to full namespace string

Tags: php, namespaces

I was wondering if there is a way to expand an aliased PHP namespace token to get the full namespace identifier.  The purpose of doing so is that our object creation factory expects a string with the full namespace so it can autoload it.  Here's a quick example:

```
<?php

use my\namespace\area as MyArea;

$goodObject = MyApp::factory('my\namespace\area\ClassName');
$badObject = MyApp::factory('MyArea\ClassName');
```

---

I am looking for some generic solution to be able to expand that NS alias out in any situation, with something equivalent to:

```
$desiredObject = MyApp::factory(resolve_namespace_alias('MyArea') . '\ClassName');
```

If anyone out there has tackled this issue, I would love to hear about how you did it.

Comment: I was thinking there might be a way via `ReflectionClass` however this too is [not possible](http://pornel.net/phpns#oo)

Comment: I did try this approach as well, and I guess it's "technically" possible to do by creating a non constructed instance of the object and getting the class name for that.  The only problem there is that the code can't be broken out to an external location for re-use since the namespace alias won't be valid in the external context.

Comment: This approach is all wrong. The main thing that's wrong about it is the static `MyApp::factory()` - global static factories are a massive antipattern. More pertinently though, the *only* way to do this is using the approach used by the `AliasExpander` utility linked below, namely parsing it out of the calling source file, which I hope you agree is a horrible way to do things and really not for production use. The reason it's not possible is because aliases are resolved to their full paths at compile time, and the information has been discarded by run time, which is when you want to access it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware to resolve a string, but the class from an object instance:

```
use my\namespace\area as MyArea;

$b = new MyArea;
$c = get_class($b);
echo $c; # my\namespace\area
```

This question is *somewhat* related: [Can't get constant from dynamic class using namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7663270/367456#7663425).

Comment: Constructing a class directly kind of defeats the purpose of the factory ;)

Comment: Using get_class() won't work for my needs.  The very reason I am needing to resolve the full namespace is to obtain instances of those objects from our various object factories.

Comment: I thought that this won't answer your question, so it's not a *real* answer, this is the closest I came up with. You can not pass a string however to a function that is in some other namespace with it's own aliasing and then expect it to resolve some other namespace's aliases - unless PHP itself provides such a function of which I'm not aware, sorry. I strongly assume no such function exists yet in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP 5.5 you can use `MyArea::class` (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_scalars).

In PHP 5.3+ you can use `AliasExpander::expand('MyArea')` (https://github.com/milo/utils#aliasexpander).

Comment: That alias expander utility uses a truly horrifying approach. I wouldn't use that in production, it would be worse than using reflection for something.