# Variable Class Names ignore "use"

Tags: php, namespaces

From other posts, it appears that if you have namespaces defined and want to dynamically create an object in another namespace, you have to construct a string and use that in the new call.  However, I'm getting a weird behavior.  It appears that this method does not work going across namespaces.

User.php:

```
namespace application\models;

class User {

        public function hello() {
                echo "Hello from User!";
        }
}
```

Controller.php:

```
namespace application\controllers;

use application\models;

require('User.php');

$userStr = 'models\\User';
//$userOne = new $userStr();  //Doesn't work. Gets a "Class 'models\User' not found" error
$userOne = new models\User();  //Works fine

$userStr = '\\application\\models\\User';
$userTwo = new $userStr();  //Works fine

$userOne->hello();
$userTwo->hello();
```

Any idea why when using a variable for the class name, I need to use the fully qualified namespace when it's in a variable, but hard coded, I can leverage the "use" command?

Comment: You can not import with `use` into variable classnames. That is a limitation of PHP.

Comment: ^ That's the answer. Just no way around it currently.

Comment: @hakre, please elaborate in an answer.

Comment: If you want to learn about diverse limitations (sure that is point of view material), a summary is available here: [PHP namespaces are flawed](http://pornel.net/phpns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not import with [`use`](http://php.net/language.namespaces.importing) into variable classnames. That is a limitation of PHP.

See as well the related questions:

- [Expanding PHP namespace alias to full namespace string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7896456/367456)
- [Can't get constant from dynamic class using namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7663270/367456)