# Dynamic instantation of namespaced methods in php

Tags: php, namespaces

There are few routers out there but I decided to create a very simple route for a very light site.

Here is my index.php

```
    $route = new Route();

    $route->add('/', 'Home');
    $route->add('/about', 'About');
    $route->add('/contact', 'Contact');
```

Here is my router:

```
<?php namespace Laws\Route;

use Laws\Controller\Home;

class Route
{
    private $_uri = array();
    private $_method = array();
    private $_route;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function add($uri, $method = null)
    {
        $this->_uri[] = '/' . trim($uri, '/');
        if ($method != null) {
            $this->_method[] = $method;
        }
    }

    public function submit()
    {
        $uriGetParam = isset($_GET['uri']) ? '/' . $_GET['uri'] : '/';

        foreach ($this->_uri as $key => $value) {
            if (preg_match("#^$value$#", $uriGetParam)) {
                $useMethod = $this->_method[$key];
                new $useMethod();     // this returns an error (cannot find Home'
                new Home(); // this actually works.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> new $useMethod(); does not work.  returns error 'cannot find Home'
>   new Home(); actually works.

What am I missing here?

Comment: try making `$useMethod` equal to `Laws\Controller\Home`. So basically `$useMethod = 'Laws\\Controller\\' . $this->_method[$key];`

Comment: @Jacob As you can see from his code he is using `use`

Comment: Right, but you cannot use `use` with variable class names, as far as I recall. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313904/variable-class-names-ignore-use

Answer (score 0):

You can use your concurrent way for calling a class or you can use this:

`call_user_func(array($classname,$methodname))`